# update date using limit and offset

Tags: mysql

what wrong in the syntax below:

```
update arts set date = "2018-06-27 04:00:00" limit 60 offset 60;
```

also tried

```
update arts set date = "2018-06-27 04:00:00" offset 60 limit 60;
```

Thanks

Comment: This seems like a overly random concept. What are you actually trying to do

Comment: @RiggsFolly, trying to update date column in phpmyadmin and getting syntax error

Comment: No not how are you trying to do it. WHAT ARE you TRYING to DO

Comment: @RiggsFolly, you really can't see what I'm trying?

Comment: @qadenza What are you trying to do? Can you please describe. What is the error message you get?

Comment: Yes I see. But it makes no sense! according to your syntax you are trying to UPDATE a random set of row from row 60 for 60 rows. Surely you understand that is WAY TO RANDOM to be sensible as rows are returned in an unordered way unless you specify an order

Comment: The is no offset in Update. so your query doesn't work at all. second Limit without order by doesn't make sense at all, but is at least valid.